# How can I use while loops in a text based game Java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, logic, game-engine

So first off is just some text showing my thought process on the way the code should work. I am super new to programming in general and just started learning java only a few days ago. I think I have a basic understanding of how oop works but I can't implement it well into my code. The use of while loops makes a bit of sense to me though so I'm just starting out with those ;D

Things I want:

a main menu with 3 options

Menu (camp)

1. Quest (activates the quest loop)
2. Go to Town (activates the town loop)
3. quit game (exits the program)

Quest
    Gameplay loop of fighting random monsters and gaining gold/score
    "monster appears"

1. fight monster
           does damage to monster
           monster does damage back
           back to main loop
2. use item
           choose item
           use item
           item effects applied
           back to main loop
3. run
   return back to main menu (activates main menu)

Town
allows you to spend gold on "gear" to increase health and damage values

"I am the blacksmith blah blah blah"

1. Upgrade Weapon (increases damage)
2. Upgrade Armor (increases health)
3. Leave Town (returns player back to main menu)

Game Ends when player dies or chooses quit game

Display a Score and thank player for playing game

Below is just a prototype of the logic

I feel like this should work but every time I run it,
it doesn't work right and just ends up doing an 
infinite loop. I'm hoping one of you guys will be able
to see why it doesn't work and kinda steer me in the right
direction. Anything would be greatly appreciated!

Also any comments on those booleans for camp, dungeon, town?
I don't know if I really needed those and its probably just
an extra bit of useless code but I'm really not sure.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class logic
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    boolean running = true;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This is a test");

    while(running)
    {
        boolean camp = true;
        boolean dungeon = false;
        boolean town = false;
        String input = in.nextLine();
        while(camp)
        {
            System.out.println("what u do?");
            System.out.println("1. go dungeon");
            System.out.println("2. go town");
            System.out.println("3. quit");
            if (input.equals("1"))
            {
                dungeon = true;
                while(dungeon)
                {
                    System.out.println("you are in the dungeon");
                    dungeon = false;
                    break;

                }



            }
            else if (input.equals("2"))
            {
                dungeon = false;
                town = true;
                while(town)
                {
                    System.out.println("you are in the town");
                    town = false;
                    break;

                }


            }
            else if (input.equals("3"))
            {
                break;


            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("invalid command!");


            }


        }


    }

    }

}
```

Comment: You probably need to assign false to camp and running somewhere.

Comment: correct me if im wrong but, I wouldn't be able to do that inside of dungeon or town because they are inside the camp and running loops

Comment: You probably want to do something in the option 3

Comment: okay so I added two lines that declare both camp and running as false into option 3 and that didnt work. I then tried just declaring camp as false and that didn't do it either...The other thing that is weird to me is that when I run the program, the only thing that shows is that "this is a test" print. I would think that the running and camp loops would automatically show since they are both declared true....but they don't. If you enter in any sort of input, this is when the infinite looping starts to happen and I end up needing to close command prompt

Comment: It waiting for an input at that line: String input = in.nextLine();

Comment: I would use an [event-driven model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming)

Comment: Okay I got it to stop doing the infinite loop. I added a label to the running loop called game and then in the 3rd option i told it to break game. I don't really know if this was a permanent fix though so I'll definitely keep this post updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't use so much while loops and instead put each section's logic into its own function then use an if-else-if / switch statement to decide which function should be called and do this in a while loop, sadly I can't test this because I haven;t got a Java environment and its been a while since I used Java.

Comment: Alright, yeah I'll definitely look into doing that. I agree that the while loops are sloppy. Like I said though making functions/objects and calling them is still a bit weird to me and I'm still learning how to do all that.

Comment: Oh yeah and I'm just using the command prompt and notepad++ for everything. If you ever get the time to test that code, that's an easy way to do so and I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: So figuring out what you suggested wasn't actually as hard as I first thought...and I got a working prototype down....so thanks for that! :D

Comment: Glad to hear, you should probably post your solution here so this question can be marked as solved/answered.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new code I came up with. I was able to figure out how to break all the different areas up into their own methods. This should make building the game world much easier :D

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LogicTest
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LogicTest game;
        game = new LogicTest(); // a new instance of the public class folder has to be created in order to use all the other methods

        game.run();


    }

    public void run() // this method is used to run the game from the main method
        {
            camp();
        }

    public void quest() 
    {
        System.out.println("you go on quest");
        camp();
    }
    public void town()
    {
        System.out.println("you go to town");
        camp();
    }
    public void camp() // this method acts as the game hub where the player can choose what they want to do next
    {
        System.out.println("you are in your camp");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println("what do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("1. go quest");
        System.out.println("2. go town");
        System.out.println("3. quit");


        String input = in.nextLine(); 
        // each one of these options just calls its respective method
                                    // the methods are what have the menus and everything for each location
        if (input.equals("1"))
        {
            quest();
        }
        else if (input.equals("2"))
        {
            town();
        }
        else if(input.equals("3")) // by leaving this empty the program has nothing else to read with this option and so it closes
        {

        }
        else 
        {
            camp();
        }
    }



}
```